# Why is query valid on sample_commits but not for commits in public github_repos dataset?

Tags: github, google-bigquery

I am running into some strange behaviour of Google's BigQuery. The dataset `bigquery-public-data.github_repos` provides table `commits` and `sample_commits`. Schema of the tables should be the same, the difference is only in the size of the table, so one can develop queries without wasting limited data.

When I run the query below on the sample data, I get the correct result of 10 commits:

```
SELECT 
  commit AS commit, 
  repo_name AS repo_name,
  committer.date AS date
FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_commits`
WHERE 
  repo_name = "torvalds/linux"
LIMIT 10
```

The strange thing is, when I run the query on the big table `commits`, I get an error message:

```
SELECT 
  commit AS commit, 
  repo_name AS repo_name,
  committer.date AS date
FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
WHERE 
  repo_name = "torvalds/linux"
LIMIT 10
```

The error message I get is:

> No matching signature for operator = for argument types: ARRAY, STRING. Supported signatures: ANY = ANY at [8:3]

From the schema table I also know, that `repo_name` is of type `STRING`, so this error confuses me a lot.

Comment: "Schema of the tables should be the same" is probably not a good assumption to always make.  If you view the details of the `sample_commits` table, you can see the query used to generate the table from the larger `commits` table.  You can see that it is `flattened` on `repo_name`, as Mikhail points out in his answer below.

Comment: Thanks for the info, didn't have this considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field `repo_name` is of STRING NULLABLE data type in `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.sample_commits` table

while same field in `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits` table is of STRING REPEATD data type

Try below instead

```
SELECT 
  commit AS commit, 
  repo_name AS repo_name,
  committer.date AS DATE
FROM 
  `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
WHERE 
  'torvalds/linux' IN UNNEST(repo_name)
LIMIT 10
```